# Suitable pattern for updating a progress bar from multiple threads (using TPL?)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar, task-parallel-library

I've been busy updating my brain with the TPL because I intend on using it for my new application (which uses .Net Framework 4.0). However I have some doubts that someone might clarify for me. Previously, I had a progress form which I would launch from the main (GUI) thread after I started the thread which needed to display its' progress. It looked something like this:

```
sortThread = New Thread(AddressOf _Sorter.Sort())
_ProgressForm = New FrmProgress()
_Sorter.ProgressForm = _ProgressForm
sortThread.Start()
progressForm.ShowDialog()
```

Basically it would initialize the thread, initialize a FrmProgress form object and assign it to the Sorter object which would then update the progress form (which contained a progress bar and some labels) from its Sort() sub on the separate thread. Updating these control properties was achieved by checking the InvokeRequired property of the FrmProgress form and if needed it would then use the Invoke() method of the control that was to be updated... ex:

```
Public Sub IncrementProgressBar(x As Integer)
   If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      pb_MainProgressBar.Invoke(Sub() IncrementProgressBar(x))
   Else
      pb_MainProgressBar.Increment(x)
   End If    
End Sub
```

Now I am interested in using TPL to launch separate worker threads (multiple) that may want to update the progress bar. Should I use the same pattern or should I consider accessing a public TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext context that was obtained in the main GUI thread? In both cases I suppose I should provide some kind of locking mechanism on the form (SyncLock?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke should be sufficient, as you are doing. If two different threads try to invoke in parallel the first one will execute first, then the second when the UI thread becomes free. The UI thread cannot service two invokes simultaneously - they are naturally handled in FIFO sequence so there is no issue with thread safety.  Any number of threads can invoke on the main thread without worrying about each other or using any additional locking mechanism.

Note, however, that any thread calling `Invoke` will block until the main thread can service the call.  If you, for example, had many threads invoking heavy code at the same time then your various threads would block on the invoke calls until they got their kick at the can, so to speak.  If you use `BeginInvoke` then the calling thread will simply continue executing and the invoked method will be placed in the UI thread's queue (which it will service as soon as it can).